# Using coder.extrinsics conditionally

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

This question refers to Matlab *coder* extrinsic functionality. Some functions like `fprintf` are extrinsic in older Matlab version, and are not extrinsic in the newer ones. Is there a way to support several Matlab versions, if `coder.extrinsics` is allowed only at the top level, and it's not possible to put it under `if` statement?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot conditionally make some functions extrinsic directly. One way would be to use two different functions like fprintf_old and fprintf_new. fprintf_old would have coder.extrinsic declaration and then calls fprintf. fprintf_new can call fprintf without extrinsic declaration. Now you can pick between the two calls by checking for your version with a condition that is constant during compilation. For example,

```
if coder.const(isOlderVersion())
  fprintf_old();
else
  fprintf_new();
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In code generation, [`feval` constructs an extrinsic call](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html#bq1h2z9-44) to the function named in the first argument. Since you can embed calls to `feval` inside of control flow, it can be used to selectively call a function extrinsically and keep the code in a single source file:

```
if isOlderVersion()
  % Call fprintf extrinsically
  feval('fprintf');
else
  fprintf();
end
```